# unable to save kibana dashboards correctly

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am trying to save kibana dashboards - I have tried the regular save as well as save to file option.  In either case, I am unable to get the same dashboard to open up - the error I see at the top is as follows:

**Error Alert**

```
No time filter Timestamped indices are configured without a failover. Waiting for time filter
```

Before saving the dashboard, I can see the logs correctly in kibana.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting or fixing this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error happens when you try to refresh the dashboard and you do not have a *Time Filter*. Try to select for example, **Last 15m** and the error should not appear more.